# How to setup lombok annotationProcessing in modern gradle 4.6 environment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, lombok, annotation-processing

This is my setup:

- AndroidStudio Lombok Plugin is installed
- Enable Annotation Processing is checked in AndroidStudio Settings
- Gradle wrapper is using version 4.6
- I am using kotlin version 1.2.71
- I am using com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1
- I tried "Invalidate cache / Restart AndroidStudio" after each change
- Lombok dependencies are defined like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2"
    kapt "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2"
}
```

When I build the app, I get the followin error:

```
Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now. 
The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to 
contain annotation processor.  
Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
    - lombok-1.18.2.jar (org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2)
```

---

I also tried this dependency setup:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2"
}
```

But then I get "cannot find symbol"-errors all over the place, because no getters/setters are generated by lombok.

Answer (score 1):

> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following
>   dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation
>   processor.
>
> *Please add them to the* `annotationProcessor` configuration.
>       - `lombok-1.18.2.jar (org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2)`

Try adding it as `annotationProcessor`:

```
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
```

---

**However**, read this: [Is it possible to use Lombok with Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027391/is-it-possible-to-use-lombok-with-kotlin)

> Lombok does not run on your source code, but on the AST. Anyway, it is
>   an annotation processor that is run at compile-time by the Java
>   compiler. ***The Kotlin compiler does not use these annotation
>   processors***. See also the answer
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/35530223/2621917 straight from the horse’s
>   mouth.

Comment: To your 1st part: sorry, pasted the wrong code snippet. My second attempt was to declare it as annotationProcessor, but then I get the "cannot find symbol"-errors. Fixed the snippet in my question. 

To your 2nd part: I also read that, but on my macbook the app runs perfectly (I am trying to setup the project on a windows machine as well).

Comment: ok...it does not run on my macbook as soon as I update everything. It was just an older version of the code that worked.