# log4j does not load Kotlin @Plugin class

Tags: logging, kotlin, log4j2

Trying to extend logging logic in my Kotlin project. 
Added converter for logs:

```
@Plugin(name = "TestConverter", category = "Converter")
@ConverterKeys("m")
class TestConverter(name: String, style: String) : LogEventPatternConverter(name, style) {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(options: Array<String>): TestConverter = TestConverter("test", Thread.currentThread().name)
    }

    override fun format(event: LogEvent?, toAppendTo: StringBuilder?) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But seems like that log4j does not see Kotlin class with @Plugin annotation.
I tried add packages in configuration explicitly, but did not help. The problem could also be with [annotation processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517325/kotlin-doesnt-see-java-lombok-accessors/35530223#35530223) for Kotlin, but not really sure if it is related.

Same class in Java works perfectly.

Any ideas/suggestions what is going wrong?

Thanks!

UPD adding log4j.xml

log4j.xml is quite standard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${env:CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%d %p %c [%t] %X %m%n}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="test" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I tried to specify package to scan `<Configuration packages="com.test">` but it didn't help. And also as I mentioned - Java class with the same configuration works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after 2 weeks had some time to go deeper into the problem.

Log4j loads plugins from `Log4j2Plugins.dat` file. They populate `@Plugin` annotated classes to this file during compilation time(which is super confusing) by `PluginProcessor` class.

So, my first assumption that it is connected to annotation processing was true.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this problem in this way .Just lookout the code it's working for me.

```
@Plugin(name="TransactionIdConverter", category = "Converter")
@ConverterKeys({"transanctionLogid","trscId"})
public class TransactionLogIdConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter{
    protected TransactionLogIdConverter(String name, String style) {
        super(name, style);
    }

    public static TransactionLogIdConverter newInstance(String[] options) {
        return new TransactionLogIdConverter("transanctionLogid",Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder toAppendTo) {
        toAppendTo.append(getTransactionId());

    }

    protected String getTransactionId() {

       String transacationId = TransactionLogIdGenerator.myTransactionId();

        return transacationId;
    }

}
```

TransactionIdGenerator.java class for generating TransactionLogId

```
public class TransactionLogIdGenerator {

       public static String  myTransactionId(){
              return "0909-0967-8678";

       }
   }
```

**Log4j.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
       status="OFF" packages="com.custom.pattern">
       <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
     <PatternLayout pattern="  Date:-%d  TransactionLogID:- %trnLogid   line Number:-%L  Location:-%l   className: %C  Message:-%m%n"/>

    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <loggers>
              <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="all" />
              <root level="all">
                     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" level="TRACE" />
                     </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);   
       public static void myTest(){
              logger.info("Sample info message");
              logger.debug("sample debug message");

       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
              myTest();
       }

}
```

Comment: Your code is Java and I am facing problems with loading Kotlin classes to log4j.

Comment: can you please update your question alongwith log4j.xml.

Comment: have added my pretty standard log4j.xml

Comment: <Logger name="com.test" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>         can you please try this